# Are table top battle games acceptable?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'd like to find out if asking questions about table top turn based strategy games such as Warhammer, War Machine, Hordes, etc. are acceptable for this community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Wargaming questions are off-topic for RPG.se as they are not about roleplaying games. Wargaming questions are on-topic at [Board & Card Games SE](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the other community.